# On defining "multivariable" functions by partial application in Haskell-like languages

Tags: haskell, idris

So. I'm actually tinkering with the Idris language, by somewhat following Brady's *Type-Driven Development with Idris*. I don't think what I written here is *that* tied to a specific programing language (and I don't know any Haskell, for that matter). But I don't know where else I could post this, given that I have no knowledge of partial-application/currying, types, lambdas and all that stuff from the mathematician's perspective.

### Some context

In the second chapter of the book the author draws attention to the following scenario.

> Given the self-explaining snippet
>
> ```
> double : Num a => a -> a
> double x = x + x
>
> rotate : Shape -> Shape
> ```
>
> where `Shape : Type` and `rotate` are holes for the type of a shape and for a function that rotates a `Shape` by 90 degrees respectively, there is an obvious pattern behind a `quadruple` and a `turn-around` function
>
> ```
> quadruple : Num a => a -> a
> quadruple x = double (double x)
>
> turn_around : Shape -> Shape
> turn around x = rotate (rotate x)
> ```
>
> which lead us to write a `twice` (high-order) function capable of applying two times the same operator.

To my eyes, there are mostly two ways to solve the problem. The first is just to follow Brady's code

```
twice : (ty -> ty) -> ty -> ty
twice f x = f (f x)
```

where he actually defines the image `twice f : ty -> ty` of the `twice` function over an arbitrary `f`<sup>1</sup>.

The second one, which seems to me a little bit more elegant, is to define `twice` by the means of a `composite` function and/or an anonymous function, by changing a little bit its signature

```
twice : (ty -> ty) -> ty
twice f = composite f f

composite : (ty_2 -> ty_3) -> (ty_1 -> ty_2) -> (ty_1 -> ty_3)
composite g f = \x => g (f x)
```

Both approaches lead to the final result

```
turn_around : Shape -> Shape
turn_around = twice rotate
```

### The question(s)

I'll try to keep my questions as clear as I can, so instead of mistreating elementary compsci terminology I will keep things concrete.

1. Let's say we have a "multivariable" function

   ```
   f : ty_1 -> ty_2 -> ... -> ty_n
   ```

   Then `f` is a function taking `x_1 : ty_1` to another function `f x_1 : ty_1 -> ... -> ty_n`. When should we choose define `f` by writing

   ```
   f x_1 = stuff
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   f x_1 ... x_{n-2} = stuff2
   ```
2. Could someone clarify me the differences between two two approaches (Brady's and mine) reported above?

---

<sup>1</sup>Yes, I'm a math student...

Comment: It is worth noting that the phrase "partial function" has a different common use than what (I think) you are using here. Usually, a ["partial function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function) is something that is like a function, except that it might not produce an output when given some of the values in its domain (because it isn't defined on that input, because it does not terminate when given that input or throws an exception on that input in a way not described by its codomain). Maybe you're thinking of [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).

Comment: Of course I meant partial application. I've updated the title. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

There's no hard and fast "rule" telling when one should use one style over another.

A function defined as

```
f x = \y => ...
```

is exactly equal to the function defined as

```
f x y = ...
```

We might prefer the first notation when we want to stress that we like to see `f` as a 1-ary function whose codomain is made of functions. We would instead use the second notation when we like to see `f` as a 2-ary function.

For function composition you wrote

```
composite g f = \x => g (f x)
```

since composition is commonly regarded as a 2-ary function. We could also have written

```
composite g f x = g (f x)
```

but this, albeit shorter, is not as clear, since it suggests the human reader to consider `composite` as a 3-ary function. Being a human, I also prefer the first form, but there would be no preference for a computer.

If I could not use composition as you did, I would have written Brady's code as

```
twice f = \x => f (f x)
```

to stress that we really want to see `twice` as a function-to-function mapping (endo-to-endo, to be picky). The two forms are completely equivalent.

---

Finally, a more mathy note: from a foundational standpoint, there is no need for the notation

```
f x1 ... xn = stuff
```

which we commonly use to define functions. To be extremely pedantic, the above does not actually define `f`, but only defines how `f` behaves when applied to `n` arguments. Since we know that that uniquely identifies `f`, we don't care about that. But, if we did, we would define `f` as we define anything else, i.e. with a defining equation of the form

```
f = something
```

and in particular

```
f = \x1 .. x2 => stuff
```

So, each definition of the form `f x1 .. xn = ...` with `n>0` can be regarded as *syntactic sugar*: a notation that we can use to program, but that we can ignore when studying the theory related to the programming language. Concretely, if I need to mathematically prove a property on all programs `P`, I don't have to consider the cases where `P` makes use of the syntactic sugar, but only the cases where every equation has the form `f = ...`, possibly involving lambdas. This simplifies the proof, since we need to deal with fewer cases.

Now, I don't know Idris too much, so I don't know if this conversion to lambdas is possible in all cases, in Idris. In Agda it would not be possible because of how dependent elimination is performed, for instance. In Coq it would instead be possible. Until you need dependent types you should be fine.

Comment: For the sake of balance, I'll add that I prefer `composite g f x = g (f x)`, and while I understand your reason for saying it "is not as clear", I like how it just uses the tools the the language as they were designed to work, in a compact form

Comment: Nitpick: "A function defined as `f x = \y => ...` is exactly equal to the function defined as `f x y = ...`" isn't quite true. In particular, 1) a `where` clause can only use `y` in the latter, 2) the monomorphism restriction breaks `f = \x -> show x` but not `f x = show x`, and 3) a few compiler optimizations (I think inlining is one) work a bit differently.